# How can i make a linq

Tags: javascript, linq.js

[image]

```
 var adreees = Variables.PolicyCustomerAddresses;
 var linq= Enumerable.From(adreees)
                .Where(linq.CUSTOMER_ADRESS_ID === correspondenceAdress && linq.CUSTOMER_ID === customerCode)
                .DefaultIfEmpty(null)
                .First();
```

adreees is an array and it is include 3 index and I want to get `CUSTOMER_ADRESS_ID === correspondenceAdress && linq.CUSTOMER_ID === customerCode` index's values.

Comment: What has this to do with javascript? Please change tag to c#

Comment: @KooiInc, it exists, [tag:linq.js]

Comment: please add some data, the result and what you like to get from the data.

Comment: i wanna just that CUSTOMER_ADRESS_ID === correspondenceAdress && linq.CUSTOMER_ID === customerCode index's values. i get this error Cannot read property 'CUSTOMER_ADRESS_ID ' of undefined

Comment: it is array 0: {ADRESS_TEXT: "XXX",CUSTOMER_ADRESS_ID : 701877}
1: {ADRESS_TEXT: "YYY",CUSTOMER_ADRESS_ID : 706023}
2: {ADRES_TEXT: "ZZZ",CUSTOMER_ADRESS_ID  : 705963}
length: 3  and i wanna get  CUSTOMER_ADRESS_ID : 706023(index2) and correspondenceAdress = 706023.

Comment: actually i get this index's values with for loop but i wanna learn linq

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$` as placeholder for the actual array and you need to write the condition as a string.

```js
var adreees = [{ CUSTOMER_ADRESS_ID: 1, CUSTOMER_ID: 17, name: 'foo' }, { CUSTOMER_ADRESS_ID: 2, CUSTOMER_ID: 17, name: 'bar' }, { CUSTOMER_ADRESS_ID: 3, CUSTOMER_ID: 17, name: 'baz' }],
    correspondenceAdress = 2,
    customerCode = 17,
    result = Enumerable.From(adreees)
        .Where("$.CUSTOMER_ADRESS_ID === correspondenceAdress && $.CUSTOMER_ID === customerCode")
        .DefaultIfEmpty(null)
        .First();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js"></script>
```

Comment: guess it does but i get this error" correspondenceAdress is not defined " but it is already defined .

Comment: you could take a text search in your IDE/editor and look for the string.

Comment: what do you mean link is broken ?

Comment: please check again add up im get any error about customerCode  but correspondenceAdress " correspondenceAdress is not defined "