# How can i get Array item By linq

Tags: javascript, linq

```
Variables.PolicyCustomerAddresses

(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {ADRES_EK: null, ADRES_ID1: 885843,  ADRES_TEXT: "XXXX", MUSTERI_ADRES_ID: "333", …}

1: {ADRES_EK: null, ADRES_ID1: 890997, ADRES_TEXT: "YYYY", MUSTERI_ADRES_ID: "222", …}

2: {ADRES_EK: null, ADRES_ID1: 890902,  ADRES_TEXT: "ZZZZ", MUSTERI_ADRES_ID: "111", …}
length: 3

correspondenceAdress == 222
```

like this and i wanna take line who `MUSTERI_ADRES_ID == 222` by linq

```
var adreeess = Variables.PolicyCustomerAddresses;
                var adrx = Enumerable.From(adreeess)
                        .Where("$.MUSTERI_ADRES_ID === correspondenceAdress ")
                        .FirstOrDefault(null)
                        .First();
```

Comment: You can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) like this: `Variables.PolicyCustomerAddresses.find(a => a.MUSTERI_ADRES_ID == correspondenceAdress)`

Comment: what about the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55626262/1447675) from yesterday?

Comment: Linq.js is redundant by the way. You can use [Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Methods) methods to do all these operatiosn

Answer (score 1):

`MUSTERI_ADRES_ID` has to be a string, as the value in the given data.

```js
var Variables = { PolicyCustomerAddresses: [{ ADRES_EK: null, ADRES_ID1: 885843,  ADRES_TEXT: "XXXX", MUSTERI_ADRES_ID: "333" }, { ADRES_EK: null, ADRES_ID1: 890997, ADRES_TEXT: "YYYY", MUSTERI_ADRES_ID: "222" }, { ADRES_EK: null, ADRES_ID1: 890902,  ADRES_TEXT: "ZZZZ", MUSTERI_ADRES_ID: "111" }] },
    correspondenceAdress = "222", // string!
    result = Enumerable.From(Variables.PolicyCustomerAddresses)
        .Where("$.MUSTERI_ADRES_ID === correspondenceAdress")
        .DefaultIfEmpty(null)
        .First();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js"></script>
```

Comment: i get this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: correspondenceAdress is not defined"

Comment: then you have to look `correspondenceAdress` where you have used it the first time and declare it.

Comment: i get it from another function it is a parameter

Comment: maybe it's wrong spelling or lower/upper case mismatch.

Comment: im not get any error .Where("$.MUSTERI_ADRES_ID === $.correspondenceAdress") with this. but result is  (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {ADRES_EK: null, ADRES_ID1: 885843,  ADRES_TEXT: "XXXX", MUSTERI_ADRES_ID: "333", …}

1: {ADRES_EK: null, ADRES_ID1: 890997, ADRES_TEXT: "YYYY", MUSTERI_ADRES_ID: "222", …}

2: {ADRES_EK: null, ADRES_ID1: 890902,  ADRES_TEXT: "ZZZZ", MUSTERI_ADRES_ID: "111", …}
length: 3 turn again same values

Comment: i have no idea, what you mean.

Comment: im not get any error .Where("$.MUSTERI_ADRES_ID === $.correspondenceAdress")  is running not give me any error but console.log(result); result is include all list again not give me only {ADRES_EK: null, ADRES_ID1: 890997, ADRES_TEXT: "YYYY", MUSTERI_ADRES_ID: "222", …} line

Comment: then you have a console, problem, which is having a time warp, which is a known problem, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays